# Excel VBA to insert comments on selected cells and filled them with pictures

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of more than 150 cells which contained hyperlinks to images on local hard,
yesterday I found a way to popup those images by inserting comments with filling the background with a picture. 
It will be tough to do this one by one, So I want a VBA script to insert comments on selected cells and fill the comments background with images which its hyperlink located in every cell.

Is That possible or should I do it manually?

Here is an Example of cells contents

```
    I1 D:\My Pictures\example 001.jpg
    I2 D:\My Pictures\example 021.jpg
    I3 D:\My Pictures\example 030.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recording a macro shows that the above is possible. A little tweaking is in order, though. As an example, the following macro creates an image pop-up via comment for `A1`.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Comm As Comment
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("A1").AddComment
    Range("A1").Comment.Visible = False
    Set Comm = Range("A1").Comment
    Comm.Shape.Fill.UserTextured "C:\foo\bar.gif"
End Sub
```

The `On Error Resume Next` is for handling ranges that already have comments, so you can keep on running the macro repeatedly. I set `.Visible` to `False` to be safe that the images don't become permanent pop-ups (should only appear on hover).

We can tweak the above further to create a subroutine that takes in a range and a string as arguments so we can call it repeatedly across ranges.

```
Sub CreatePopUp(TargetRange As Range, PathToImage As String)
    Dim Comm As Comment
    On Error Resume Next
    With TargetRange
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Visible = False
        Set Comm = .Comment
    End With
    Comm.Shape.Fill.UserTextured PathToImage
End Sub
```

The above can be called like so:

```
Sub MassPopUp()
    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In [A1:A10]
        CreatePopUp rCell, "Blah"
    Next
End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

### **EDIT:**

If your date is in, for example, `I1:I10`, and they contain the ***exact*** paths to the image files, then the above can be written like so:

```
Sub MassPopUp()
    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In [I1:I10]
        CreatePopUp rCell, rCell.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

`rCell.Value` will take the value inside the cell, pass it to the subroutine that inserts an image, and apply it as a comment to `rCell` with the proper image extracted. This should **not** fail. Just make sure the value in the cell are proper paths to their respective files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can't figure out how I cant set the background image with the path which located in cell, when path in A1 is different than path in A2.
Excuse me for understanding, I am beginner with VBA and coding stuff

Comment: Do you mean: A1 has different image than A2, and then a different one again for A3, etc?

Comment: Yes, Every cell has hyperlink to its image. So as I said I want to insert comments on those cells while adding its hyperlinks images to comments as background

Comment: What is your complete range containing hyperlinks? Are you using aliases or the exact path image is in each cell without an alias?

Comment: Thank you very much, It works But there is a problem.
I want to fit images into comment box, Images now showed at its full size and that is not working with my case.

Comment: I have change "Fill.UserTextured" to "Fill.UserPicture" and now image fit into comment box :)))